# Named lambda in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I need to write a recursive helper function and do not need to give it global scope, but I need to reference it to achieve the recursion.

Emacs lisp has `fset`, which assigns to the function-cell of a symbol. What is the equivalent in common lisp?

Comment: I could assign a lambda function to a symbol and then `(funcall )` that symbol, but there must be a prettier way.

Comment: Look into labels: http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/speope_fletcm_scm_macrolet.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out that this is a idiom common enough to be in [alexandria](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/). From alexandria code:

```
(defmacro named-lambda (name lambda-list &body body)
  "Expands into a lambda-expression within whose BODY NAME denotes the corresponding function."
  `(labels ((,name ,lambda-list ,@body))
 #',name))
```

Here's a usage example:

```
(let ((! ;; Everything can be a symbol :D
   ;; Definition here
   (named-lambda self (n)
         (case n
           (1 1)
           (otherwise (* n
                 (self (1- n)))))))) ;; Recurse here
  ;; How to call it
  (funcall ! 6))
```

Comment: P.S. I just wanted to add an example for Lars Brinkhoff's answer.

Comment: Interestingly, Scheme had a `named-lambda` in its very early days but it was dropped in R³RS in 1986.

Answer (score 2):

What malisper said.

Or if you really need a named lambda:

```
(defmacro named-lambda (name args &body body)
  `(labels ((,name ,args ,@body))
     #',name))
```